# Fullscreen SVG without Scaling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Is there any way I can make the SVG 100% by 100% but disabling scaling?

I need the image to be in the middle of the page (both horizontal and vertical). The problem here is that I want to display the areas that are outside of the SVG artboard too, so centralizing with CSS wouldn't work for me. I know that displaying those areas is possible if you have an image with 100% width and a set height or vice-versa.

This was possible with Flash but I have not find a way to do it with SVG and HTML.

**Normal SVG:**

```
<svg style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

**100% Width**

```
<svg style="width: 100%; height: 100px;">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Now, when you take the same code and make it 100% by 100%, it scales the image. Is there a way yo stop this?

**100% by 100% Plus imaginary no-scale code**

```
<svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" ##no_scale_code##>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

**Here is a codepen example of the code I have so far:
http://codepen.io/cecilomar/pen/Gcpys**

Answer (score 1):

Your codepen example SVG includes a `viewBox` attribute.  If you don't want the SVG to be scaled when you make the dimensions larger, then remove the `viewBox`.

Comment: Hey thank you. That is very close to what I want. Now, the only thing that would make it perfect is if I could center-align it.

Comment: There are several different ways to centre an element on a page.  If you search this site, or Google, you should find them easily.